# 301 Redirect with Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, proxy

I am currently struggling to resolve an issue stemming from a reverse proxy. We are running a reverse proxy from **page.example.com** to **example.com/page/** . This original subdomain content is generated from Unbounce.com , and attached to the subdomain.

Problem: We want the subdomain ported to a sub-directory for SEO reasons. The reverse proxy works great, and properly ports the sub-domain, to the sub-directory. Our current issue is that the **page.example.com** is still getting indexed in Google. We'd like to install 301 redirects to allow only the sub-directory to get indexed. Because we do not have direct access to the content on **page.example.com** , I cannot put an htaccess file in place to redirect that traffic. Unbounce also charges based on "traffic", and the reverse proxy breaks their tracking information.

They have told us, if we put the 301's in place, their tracking info should push to the new URL structure, and work again.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be fantastic.

- Joe

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: Ok, I will try there. Thank you.